# AngularJS Directive to include file content

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I´m trying to create a directive in AngularJS for a small templating issue. In my HTML-File I have this:

```
<div myinclude="header.tpl.html"></div>
```

My directive should transform this to that:

```
<div>{content of file: header.tpl.html}</div>
```

This is how far (or not) I´ve come, but I guess, I´m missing a piece:

```
    myApp.directive('myinclude', function () {
    return {
        compile: function compile( tElement, tAttributes ) {
            console.log(tAttributes.myinclude); // logs filename
            return {
                templateURL: tAttributes.myinclude
            };
         }
     };
});
```

Has anyone done something like this before, and is willing to share?

Comment: Can you provide a plunker

Comment: Sure: http://plnkr.co/edit/PLjjx2Xuxs1L2lkuvrSz

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**[Here is the working plunker.](http://plnkr.co/edit/FOPMbVNJ8PFJdW1gJVHm?p=preview)**

Try something like this:

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.name = 'World';
    $scope.setValue = function(ele) {
     console.log(ele)
    };
});

app.directive("myInclude",function(){
 return {
     restrict : 'A',
      link : function(scope, element, attrs){
          scope.getContentUrl = attrs["myInclude"];
      },
      template: "content of file : {{getContentUrl}}"
    }
});
```

**HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="plunker">

  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>AngularJS Plunker</title>
    <script>document.write('<base href="' + document.location + '" />');</script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script data-require="angular.js@1.4.x" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.8/angular.js" data-semver="1.4.8"></script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <p>Hello {{name}}!</p>

 <div my-include="header.tpl.html"></div>
  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: Getting closer, but not exactly what I wanted to get:

`<div myinclude="header.tpl.html" class="ng-scope">
<!-- ngInclude: getContentUrl() -->
<div ng-include="getContentUrl()" class="ng-scope">{content of file: header.tpl.html }
</div>
</div>`

Comment: i gave what was explained can u please explain a bit more

Comment: I would rather have the DIV-Tag just filled with the content like this:

`<div>{content of file: header.tpl.html}</div>`

Comment: have you tried this ---   
.directive('myinclude', function() {
       return {
           restrict: 'E',
           link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
               scope.tmpName = attrs.myinclude;
           },
           template: '{content of file: {{tmpName}} }'
       }
    });

Comment: Wouldn´t that just print {content of file: header.tpl.html}?

I´d like to have the actual content of that file included between the DIVs. :-)

Comment: oh you mean  {content of file: HI this is content of my file } right

Comment: exactly. I´ve added a header.tpl.html to your plunker. Just without the {content of file: } then

Comment: Hm, I forked your plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/fkWexITBhMB88dvCz04M ! works, but looks a little bit strange now.

Comment: actually you've not made me clear about the template file i thought it contains just a text , now as it contains html i just added a jquery method and updated plunker link have a look at

Comment: Sorry about the irritation. That works and I´m going to need jQuery anyway. Thanks @ngLover

Comment: No not at all , no irritation happy to help you. :)

Answer (score 0):

Its working...

```
app.directive('productDescription',function(){
return {
restrict:'E',
templateUrl: 'product-description.html'
};
});
```